# Groovy create 2 dim array [][] from string

Tags: arrays, string, groovy

```
string = """
name:bla1-service,
  version:Sprint-91.0.0
  
  name:bla2-service,
  version:Sprint-93.0.0
  
  name:cbla3-service,
  version:Sprint-93.0.0
  
  name:bla4-service,
  version:Sprint-93.0.0
  
"""
```

end result should be an array

```
myArray = [[bla1-service,version:Sprint-91.0.0],[bla2-service,Sprint-93.0.0] ...]
```

i can use a for loop to search for string like "name" and "version" and build this but i figure there must be a simpler way (maybe using split(",")?)
can anyone suggest a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something straight-forward with regex:

```
String string = """
name:bla1-service,
  version:Sprint-91.0.0
  
  name:bla2-service,
  version:Sprint-93.0.0
  
  name:cbla3-service,
  version:Sprint-93.0.0
  
  name:bla4-service,
  version:Sprint-93.0.0
  
"""

def res = []
string.eachMatch( /name:([^,]+),\s+version:(\S+)/ ){ _, name, version -> res << [ name, version ] }

assert res.toString() == '[[bla1-service, Sprint-91.0.0], [bla2-service, Sprint-93.0.0], [cbla3-service, Sprint-93.0.0], [bla4-service, Sprint-93.0.0]]'
```